I want to show the graph for the first 12 values in the column?
The problem in this code is that it shows on one year, not all of the years. Can you help me fix the code to show all the years?
ks['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(ks['Deadline']).dt.year

unique_categories = ks['Category'].unique()

for category in unique_categories:
    product_df = ks[ks['Category'] == category]
    
    product_df = product_df.head(12)
    
    product_counts = product_df.groupby('Year').size()

    plt.plot(product_counts.index, product_counts.values, marker='o', linestyle='-', label=category)

    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title(f'Count of {category} Category Over the Years (First 12 Entries)')
    plt.xticks(product_counts.index, rotation=45, ha='right')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()


enter image description here how to fix this probelm?

Add a sample of your dataframe, or it is almost impossible to help

Have a check on what is in product_df.
As it only takes first 12 it might only have only 1 unique year.

how to show all years then?

try removing that line.
